# How to use for loop to pass a line of string from text file as separate variable for another script in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop

I am writing a bash script that accepts a `manifest.txt` file. It should cycle through each row of that text file and call another script to pass the text string from the row of the text file after separating the string of text by the space delimiter.

I am stuck on figuring out how to split the text string; I tried to use `cut -d' '`, but it has not worked for me.

Here's the example of the text file:

```
20200451310 B.315
30203131340 Pam 3781, no.1
20200461200 B.16
20200471180 B.116, B.198
20200471190 B.129
10107291410 B.102
30203141220 Pam 3870, no. 1
20200481160 B.525
```

Here's the bash script I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash 
IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator
set -f          # disable globbing
for i in $(cat < "${manifest.txt}"); do
  echo " $i"
  uid = ${i | cut -d' ' -f1}
  string = ${i | cut -d' ' -f2-10}   
  echo "uid is ${uid}"
  echo "string is ${string}"
  /anotherscript.sh ${uid} ${string}
done
```

The result should be, for example:

```
/anotherscript.sh "30203141220" "Pam 3870, no. 1"
```

Comment: Have a look at [BashFAQ/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1521462/3266847) to see how to read a file line by line.

Comment: Then, use https://www.shellcheck.net to get pointers about common mistakes (spaces around `=` in assignments etc.).

Comment: You're using `${ }`, but you mean `$( )` for command substitution. The command `i | cut -d' ' -f1` won't work, you have to pipe `$i` to `cut` somehow, for example with `cut -d' ' -f1 <<< "$i"`.

Comment: But really, instead of using `cut`, you should read each line into two variables and let Bash to the splitting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your script to this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r uid string; do
    ./anotherscript.sh "$uid" "$string"
done < manifest.txt
```

A laundry list of mistakes in your attempt:

- `"${manifest.txt}"` tries to perform variable expansion on `manifest.txt`, which isn't a variable name, leading to an error; you want `manifest.txt` instead
- `cat < somefile` can be just `cat somefile`
- In Bash, `for i in $(cat somefile)` can be simplified to `for i in $(< somefile)`
- But really, you want to read lines with

  ```sh
  read IFS= read -r i; do ...; done < manifest.txt
  ```
- `i | cut -d' ' -f1` doesn't make `cut` read `$i`; you have to use something like `cut -d' ' -f1 <<< "$i"` instead
- `${somecommand}` is the wrong syntax; for command substitution, you want `$(somecommand)` instead
- Assignments can't have blanks around `=`: `uid = something` should be `uid=something`
- To split a string, read into multiple variables with `read` instead of using `cut`:

  ```sh
  while read -r uid string; do ... done < manifest.txt
  ```
- `/anotherscript.sh` is probably the wrong path and should be `./anotherscript.sh` instead
- arguments in `/anotherscript.sh ${uid} ${string}` should be quoted:

  ```sh
  ./anotherscript.sh "$uid" "$string"
  ```